# Table out of the right margin of the template

Tags: tables, booktabs

I am using booktabs library to make my table in latex. However, I noticed that due to the size of the table it goes out of the right margin. I tried to follow several recommendations from several posts but none did work for me. My code is the following:

```
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\caption{Classification, FID and IS performance for all the experimental protocol scenarios. }
\label{er:tbl2}
{\small
\begin{tabular}{*9c}
\toprule
 Case &  \multicolumn{4}{c}{dv1} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{dv2}\\
 & cla& score1& score2& score3& cla& score1& score2& score3\\
\midrule
\textbf{Claas1}   &  {49.34$\%$} &   &  &    & {44.73$\%$}  &  &   &  \\
\textbf{Claas2}   & \textbf{52.52$\%$} & \textbf{59.44} & \textbf{2.16} & 
         \textbf{2.16} &  \textbf{47.11$\%$} & \textbf{49.77} & \textbf{2.21} 
         & \textbf{2.21}\\
\textbf{Claas3}   &  49.92$\%$ & 60.13 & 2.01 & 2.01 & 46.23$\%$ & 50.33 & 
          2.05 & 2.05\\
\textbf{Claas4}  &  50.29$\%$ & 60.10 & 2.00 & 2.00  & 46.55$\%$ & 49.95 & 
         2.01 & 2.01\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
```

How can I reduce the size or stretch the table within the range of my template's page?

Comment: Could you please add the documentclass you are currently using?

Comment: Probably `\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*9c@{}}` might help

Comment: for start insert `\setlength\tabcolsep{5pt}`
 before `\begin{tabular}`, however your code for table can be further improved ...

Comment: @Zarko your command push a bit more within the range, but still.

Comment: @konstantin, it may be with your document class, which is unknown to us. With standard `article` this is not  a case. Please extend your document to complete small document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`, which reproduce your problem.

Comment: @konstantin, any news? you got (so far) three answers, which solve your problem, but not upvote any of them nor accept ones which best fit your expectation ...

Answer (score 2):

The code in example 2 ensure that the table is within margins. However, in example 1, I suggest some (in my opinion) improvements to your table. Right aligned figure columns, the per cent sign in the heading and increased space between table and caption:

**Example 1**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, caption}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\caption{Classification, FID and IS performance for all the experimental protocol scenarios. }
\label{er:tbl2}
{\small
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l*{8}{r}}
\toprule
 Case &  \multicolumn{4}{c}{dv1} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{dv2}\\
 \cmidrule{2-5}\cmidrule{6-9}
 & cla (\%)& score1& score2& score3& cla (\%)& score1& score2& score3\\
\midrule
\textbf{Claas1}   &  {49.34} &   &  &    & {44.73}  &  &   &  \\
\textbf{Claas2}   & \textbf{52.52} & \textbf{59.44} & \textbf{2.16} & 
         \textbf{2.16} &  \textbf{47.11} & \textbf{49.77} & \textbf{2.21} 
         & \textbf{2.21}\\
\textbf{Claas3}   &  49.92 & 60.13 & 2.01 & 2.01 & 46.23 & 50.33 & 
          2.05 & 2.05\\
\textbf{Claas4}  &  50.29 & 60.10 & 2.00 & 2.00  & 46.55 & 49.95 & 
         2.01 & 2.01\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**Exemple 2**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, caption}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\caption{Classification, FID and IS performance for all the experimental protocol scenarios. }
\label{er:tbl2}
{\small
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{9}{c}}
\toprule
 Case &  \multicolumn{4}{c}{dv1} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{dv2}\\
 & cla& score1& score2& score3& cla& score1& score2& score3\\
\midrule
\textbf{Claas1}   &  {49.34$\%$} &   &  &    & {44.73$\%$}  &  &   &  \\
\textbf{Claas2}   & \textbf{52.52$\%$} & \textbf{59.44} & \textbf{2.16} & 
         \textbf{2.16} &  \textbf{47.11$\%$} & \textbf{49.77} & \textbf{2.21} 
         & \textbf{2.21}\\
\textbf{Claas3}   &  49.92$\%$ & 60.13 & 2.01 & 2.01 & 46.23$\%$ & 50.33 & 
          2.05 & 2.05\\
\textbf{Claas4}  &  50.29$\%$ & 60.10 & 2.00 & 2.00  & 46.55$\%$ & 49.95 & 
         2.01 & 2.01\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have many columns, the simplest is here to reduce the value of `\tabcolsep` (6pt by default). I took the opportunity to improve the layout of the table, using three (trimmed) `\cmidrule`s, `\multirow` for the first cell of the first column and added some vertical padding to the cells and caption. Also a supplementary empty column to separate the two groups of columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs,array, caption, multirow, makecell}%
\captionsetup{ justification=centering, skip=4pt}
\usepackage{showframe} 
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\setcellgapes{3pt}\makegapedcells
\let\cmidrulewidth\lightrulewidth
\caption{Classification, FID and IS performance for all the experimental protocol scenarios. }
\label{er:tbl2}
\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}c*9c}
\toprule
\multirowcell{2}[0pt][l]{Case} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{dv1} & & \multicolumn{4}{c}{dv2}\\
 & cla& score1& score2& score3& & cla& score1& score2& score3\\
\cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule(lr){2-5}\cmidrule(l){7-10}
Claas1 & 49.34$\%$ & & & & & {44.73$\%$} & & & \\
Claas2 & \textbf{52.52$\%$} & \textbf{59.44} & \textbf{2.16} &
         \textbf{2.16} & & \textbf{47.11$\%$} & \textbf{49.77} & \textbf{2.21}
         & \textbf{2.21}\\
Claas3 & 49.92$\%$ & 60.13 & 2.01 & 2.01 & & 46.23$\%$ & 50.33 &
          2.05 & 2.05\\
Claas4 & 50.29$\%$ & 60.10 & 2.00 & 2.00 & & 46.55$\%$ & 49.95 &
         2.01 & 2.01\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For completnes: with use `siunitx` package for `S` columns, `etoolbox` and `xparse` for determining numbers in the boldface shape and shortness for `\multicolumn` cells:

**Edit:** 
solution now consider handling of the `\bfseries` in the new LaTeX (see [answer of Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/530451/siunitx-is-feature-of-the-mode-text-changed)).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newrobustcmd\B{\DeclareFontSeriesDefault[rm]{bf}{b}\bfseries}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}
    {\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\caption{Classification, FID and IS performance for all the experimental protocol scenarios. }
\label{er:tbl2}
    \sisetup{detect-weight, 
             mode=text,
             table-format=2.2} 
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                      >{\bfseries}l
                                  S[table-space-text-post=\,\%]<{\,\%}
                                  S
                             *{2}{S[table-format=1.2]}
                             *{2}{S}
                                  S[table-format=1.2]
                                  S[table-format=1.2,
                                    table-space-text-post=\,\%]<{\,\%}
                             }
    \toprule
\multirow{2.4}{*}{Case}
        &   \mcc[4]{dv1}  
        &   \mcc[4]{dv2}                                \cr
        \cmidrule(l){2-5}\cmidrule(l){6-9}
        & \mcc{cla} & {score 1} & {score 2} & {score 3} 
        & {cla}     & {score 1} & {score 2} & \mcc{score 3}  \cr
   \midrule
Claas 1 &   49.34   &           &           &   
        &   44.73   &           &           &   \mcc{}  \cr
Claas 2 &\B 52.52   &\B 59.44   &\B 2.16    &\B 2.16
        &\B 47.11   &\B 49.77   &\B 2.21    &\B 2.21    \cr
Claas 3 &   49.92   &   60.13   &   2.01    &   2.01 
        &   46.23   &   50.33   &   2.05    &   2.05    \cr
Claas 4 &   50.29   &   60.10   &   2.00    &   2.00  
        &   46.55   &   49.95   &   2.01    &   2.01    \cr
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]