# Bold number in siunitx column with SF font

Tags: siunitx, sans-serif, s-column-type

I would like to achieve exactly the same thing that was questioned and answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/530451/siunitx-is-feature-of-the-mode-text-changed) but with SF font.

This works:

> ```
> \documentclass[11pt]{standalone}
> \usepackage{siunitx}
>    \sisetup{detect-weight,
>             table-format=2.2}
> \usepackage{etoolbox}
>
> \DeclareFontSeriesDefault[rm]{bf}{b}
> \newcommand\B{\bfseries}
>
> \begin{document}
> abc \textbf{ab}
> \begin{tabular}{ |S[mode=text] | S |}
>    12.34   &   12.34   \\
> \B  12.34   &\B 12.34   \\
> \end{tabular}
> \end{document}
> ```

But with

```
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
```

it does not (it uses extended bold, so the numbers are not aligned)

I tried changing

```
\DeclareFontSeriesDefault[rm]{bf}{b}
```

to

```
\DeclareFontSeriesDefault[sf]{bf}{b}
```

with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command

```
\DeclareFontSeriesDefault[sf]{bf}{b}
```

would probably work, but unfortunately as [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27875/263372) stated neither Computer Modern nor Latin Modern supports bold (not extended) in their Sans Serif variant.